# SQL 2008 install failed - Could not find the Database Engine startup handle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

My SQL 2008 install failed, I'm getting this error:

```
Could not find the Database Engine startup handle
```

This happens after uninstalling  SQL Server 2008 and trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2, any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe [something is wrong with your iso extraction](http://www.msbicentral.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/88/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/80/FLASH-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Error-Could-Not-Find-Database-Engine-Startup-Handle.aspx)...?

try this:

> I burned the ISO to DVD media and then mapped my Virtual PC image DVD drive to my laptop's physical DVD drive. The installation went through without any issues.

or this:

> And, having had a successful installation with the RAR-extracted files, it wasn’t too hard for me to figure out which of the alternatives was the “right” answer…

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You should contact Microsoft support, since you paid a lot of money for this software!

Alternatively, you could have used Google:  http://thesqldude.com/tag/could-not-find-the-database-engine-startup-handle/